# Installing STAC on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, installation, ocaml

I am trying to install STAC to perform taint analysis. I have installed the per-requisite for STAC which is frama-c. Then I checkout the svn from http://code.google.com/p/tanalysis/

When I run make from inside the tanalysis directory. It lands into couple of problems finding difficult to include libraries for Cil.

```
    Unbound Cil
```

I fix the path by adding

```
   -I /usr/local/share/frama-c/lib -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.12.1/cil/
```

But again when I run make, it gives an error

```
b/ocaml/3.12.1/cil/ -I /usr/lib/frama-c/ -c ptranal.ml
File "ptranal.ml", line 135, characters 36-43:
Error: This expression has type Cil_types.lhost * Cil_types.offset
   but an expression was expected of type
     Cil.lval = Cil.lhost * Cil.offset
make: *** [ptranal] Error 2
```

Please help me to build STAC and do the taint analysis.

Comment: `-I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.12.1/cil/`: Frama-C does not install anything there. If this directory exists on your system, it may be because you previously installed a version of Cil. Do not try to use it: Frama-C comes with its own, modified version of Cil.

Comment: If I use the default setting, here is the error: `ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I /usr/local/share/frama-c/lib -c olf.ml
File "olf.ml", line 53, characters 0-8:
Error: Unbound module Cil
make: *** [olf] Error 2`

Comment: I also tried with modifying the path from lib to libc. But the same error appears, `Unbound module Cil`. I tried with this change because lib is not present. Please help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in STAC's Makefile.

```
CFLAGS=-I $(FRAMAC_SHARE)/lib -c
```

should be replaced by (not tested)

```
FRAMAC_LIBDIR:=$(shell frama-c -print-lib-path)
CFLAGS=-I $(FRAMAC_LIBDIR) -c
```

There's absolutely no reason that FRAMAC_LIBDIR should be a subdirectory of FRAMAC_SHARE.

Comment: Sorry, the solution did not help me build. This is the error:ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I [kernel] user error: option `-print-lib-dir' is unknown.                      use `frama-c -help' for more information. [kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input. -c uref.ml
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** [uref] Error 2

Comment: I tried removing -print-lib-dir, but this did not help again, the below is the error: ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I /lib -c uref.ml
ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I /lib -c setp.ml
ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I /lib -c steensgaard.ml
ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I /lib -c olf.ml
File "olf.ml", line 53, characters 0-8:
Error: Unbound module Cil
make: *** [olf] Error 2
Probably CIL packages are not found. I have installed CIL. Please help

Comment: My bad, the option's name is `-print-lib-path` (or `-print-libpath`) as mentioned in the output of `frama-c -kernel-help`. Sorry for the noise, I'll correct the answer itself to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Virgile. I am getting another `error: ocamlc -for-pack taint-analysis -I /usr/local/lib/frama-c -c olf.ml
File "olf.ml", line 92, characters 30-40:
Error: Unbound module Pretty
make: *** [olf] Error 2`

Comment: `Pretty` is an old module from legacy Cil, that went away in the latter versions of Frama-C (Nitrogen IIRC), after having been superseded by Ast_printer for some years. It looks like STAC is not compatible with recent versions of Frama-C, but I'm afraid that porting the code is a bit out of scope on StackOverflow.